# How to run the C++ .exe file from C#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I will start from the C++ application to explain my exact requirement. I had a C++ application , which takes an input (a small command called "run") from console (keyboard)  with out using any arguments( C++ application is using getchar() in the project). well the problem i am able to run the exe file from C# using System.Diagnostics.Process, but i want to enter the command "run" programitically in C# to execute C++ Application.  Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What is the problem with `System.Diagnostics.Process`? It's the usual way.

Comment: Well, you can redirect the console output of your C# program to your program which accepts `run`. But why doing it so complicated? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. You need to redirect the spawned process's input stream so that you can write to it directly:

```
var proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

proc.Start();
var sw = proc.StandardInput;
```

Now this will write to your process's standard input, just as if you had typed the text using the keyboard:

```
sw.WriteLine("run something");
```

Finally, when you are done writing, don't forget to clean up:

```
sw.Close();
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```

Comment: Hi Jon.. its working but the problem is , when i use sw.WriteLine("run something");  its printing junk characters in the process console.. as it is printing junk characters i am getting wrong output

Comment: @Bhuvan: We can't debug this on SO, especially not without seeing code.

Comment: May i know,which code do you mean?  because i can share you the CPP code and they are not using any encoding in their app as i guess

Comment: hi JON yeah finally this is working...i am closing the stream very early which is making problem for me sw.Close();.. i realized and i solved my problem.. But i had one more doubt that when i use consoleWindow.RedirectStandardOutput = true; i am able to write the output to the file partially.. but i failed to write complete output to a  file, i am not getting what i am exactly doing... one more thing, can i print the output in console and writhe same output to the file simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Use ProcessStartInfo class
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "run.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.Arguments = "-f j ";

    try
    {
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
```